# Strange <canvas> line rendering with round lineJoin and non-integer scale

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas

Some lines with `lineJoin="round"` are strangely rendered on certain scales, here is an example with a scale of 1.403619311470477 and without it: https://jsfiddle.net/kxjcosgf/2/

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="2000"> </canvas>

<script>
const points = "45.13869240187139,481.020616681278,45.13869240187139,480.72980663647314,44.84788235706651,479.5665664572536,44.70247733466407,477.9671112108268,44.84788235706651,477.53089614361943,44.84788235706651,477.385491121217,44.993287379468946,476.80387103160723,45.28409742427383,476.22225094199746,46.44733760349335,475.059010762778,47.319767737907995,474.9136057403755,47.90138782751775,475.34982080758283,48.19219787232263,475.7860358747902,48.483007917127516,476.5130609868024,48.62841293952995,476.94927605400966,48.33760289472507,477.67630116602186".split(",")

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
ctx.lineWidth = 2
ctx.lineCap = "round"
ctx.lineJoin = "round"

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(points[0], points[1])
for (let i = 2; i < points.length; i += 2) {
  ctx.lineTo(points[i], points[i + 1])
}
ctx.stroke()

ctx.scale(1.403619311470477, 1.403619311470477)
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(points[0], points[1])
for (let i = 2; i < points.length; i += 2) {
  ctx.lineTo(points[i], points[i + 1])
}
ctx.stroke()

window.scrollBy(0, 400)
</script>
```

I expect a scaled version of the top stroke (marked blue), but get a strange ray on Chrome 94.0 coming out of it instead.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug since it's not reproducible on Chrome 93

Comment: Definitely a bug (a rounding error in Skia's GPU code-path). However it's quite weird because I can't repro in  any other branch of Chromium (i.e I couldn't make a correct bisection, even using the exact same build...). So, it seems to work well in current Canary, which could mean it's been fixed, but in the mean time, it may not have been. So please head to https://crbug.com to open a new issue anyway, noting clearly that this affects the stable branch. As an ugly workaround, you can force CPU rendering by passing `{ willReadFrequently: true }` init options to `getContext()`